# Is 二人の顔はそっくりだ a possible way to say "Both of their faces look the same"?

Tags: verbs, expressions, english-to-japanese, idioms

This is my attempt at translating the sentence "Both of their faces look the same":

> 二人の顔はそっくりだ

Does it make sense or is it completely wrong?

Comment: 二人の顔は同じように見える sounds better

Comment: stupid me, I read the question wrong and tried to answer a Japanese to English translation, rather than the English to Japanese...  9_9. Deleted my answer.

Comment: @Kent... Your Japanese makes enough sense to be understandable, and that's the most important aspect of communication. But user27223 is correct as well, there are better ways to say it... Could you clarify something?  Where is this English sentence coming from? Because it seems like there would be more natural ways to express that idea, even in English.

Comment: @user27223 I don't think 同じように見える sounds better than OP's translation.

Comment: There're several ways to say that depending on the context... 「二人は顔がそっくりだ」「二人はそっくりな顔をしている」とかいろいろ・・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

> 二人の顔はそっくりだ

is a perfectly natural way to say this.

There is also the idiomatic expression [瓜二つ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%93%9C%E4%BA%8C%E3%81%A4-442008) for "look (completely) alike"

> 二人は瓜二つだ

(or variations on this, like 「二人は瓜二つの顔をしている」「二人の顔は瓜二つだ」.)

Comment: Could one argue that the latter sounds inelegant due to repeating syllables/concepts (**ふた**り・**ふた**つ) or is it nothing to worry about? Compare to e.g. English "drinking a drink".

Comment: @kuchitsu いや別に大丈夫だと思います、全然気にならないです